# BrowserStack Error: browserType.connect: Browser has been closed

Tags: node.js, playwright, browserstack

I am currently learning how to work with browserStack. I cloned the playwright sample repository using this tutorial https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/playwright/getting-started/nodejs   and set user and accessKey. I runned sample few times and all was fine. But after the last update that was released a few hours ago I got this error.

```
Error: browserType.connect: Browser has been closed
```

I didn't change anything in the sample only started it.

here my log file

> `! 2023-10-09 20:12:16 - [32minfo[39m: Reading configs from F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\browserstack.yml ! 2023-10-09 20:12:20 - [31merror[39m: Error: LocalError: Disconnected ! at BrowserStackSetup.setupBrowserstackLocal (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\helpers\BrowserStackSetup.js:1:17190) ! at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) ! at async BrowserStackSetup.initialize (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\helpers\BrowserStackSetup.js:1:14974) ! at async run (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\bin\playwright\command.js:2:29240) ! at async captureError (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\bin\runner.js:2:4062) ! 2023-10-09 20:12:47 - [32minfo[39m: Reading configs from F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\browserstack.yml ! 2023-10-09 20:12:50 - [31merror[39m: Error: LocalError: Disconnected ! at BrowserStackSetup.setupBrowserstackLocal (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\helpers\BrowserStackSetup.js:1:17190) ! at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) ! at async BrowserStackSetup.initialize (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\helpers\BrowserStackSetup.js:1:14974) ! at async run (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\bin\playwright\command.js:2:29240) ! at async captureError (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\bin\runner.js:2:4062) ! 2023-10-09 20:15:53 - [32minfo[39m: Reading configs from F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\browserstack.yml ! 2023-10-09 20:15:56 - [31merror[39m: Error: LocalError: Disconnected ! at BrowserStackSetup.setupBrowserstackLocal (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\helpers\BrowserStackSetup.js:1:21021) ! at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) ! at async BrowserStackSetup.initialize (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\helpers\BrowserStackSetup.js:1:15290) ! at async run (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\bin\playwright\command.js:2:25443) ! at async captureError (F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\node_modules\browserstack-node-sdk\src\bin\runner.js:2:1995) ! 2023-10-09 20:17:18 - [32minfo[39m: Reading configs from F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\browserstack.yml ! 2023-10-09 20:17:21 - [32minfo[39m: Local binary started successfully ! 2023-10-09 20:17:22 - [32minfo[39m: Getting your playwright config from F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\playwright.config.js ! 2023-10-09 20:17:22 - [32minfo[39m: Adding browserstack configs to setup for Observability ! 2023-10-09 20:17:23 - [32minfo[39m: Introducing BrowserStack Test Observability with enhanced debugging & insights for your tests. Please visit https://observability.browserstack.com to get access. ! 2023-10-09 20:17:37 - [32minfo[39m: Deleting F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\playwright-browserstack-sdk.config.js ! 2023-10-09 20:17:40 - [32minfo[39m: Local binary stopped ! 2023-10-09 20:38:05 - [32minfo[39m: Reading configs from F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\browserstack.yml ! 2023-10-09 20:38:09 - [32minfo[39m: Local binary started successfully ! 2023-10-09 20:38:11 - [32minfo[39m: Getting your playwright config from F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\playwright.config.js ! 2023-10-09 20:38:11 - [32minfo[39m: Adding browserstack configs to setup for Observability ! 2023-10-09 20:38:11 - [32minfo[39m: Introducing BrowserStack Test Observability with enhanced debugging & insights for your tests. Please visit https://observability.browserstack.com to get access. ! 2023-10-09 20:38:24 - [32minfo[39m: Deleting F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\playwright-browserstack-sdk.config.js ! 2023-10-09 20:38:27 - [32minfo[39m: Local binary stopped ! 2023-10-09 21:24:29 - [32minfo[39m: Reading configs from F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\browserstack.yml ! 2023-10-09 21:24:33 - [32minfo[39m: Local binary started successfully ! 2023-10-09 21:24:34 - [32minfo[39m: Getting your playwright config from F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\playwright.config.js ! 2023-10-09 21:24:34 - [32minfo[39m: Adding browserstack configs to setup for Observability ! 2023-10-09 21:24:35 - [32minfo[39m: Introducing BrowserStack Test Observability with enhanced debugging & insights for your tests. Please visit https://observability.browserstack.com to get access. ! 2023-10-09 21:24:48 - [32minfo[39m: Deleting F:\git\node-js-playwright-browserstack\playwright-browserstack-sdk.config.js ! 2023-10-09 21:24:51 - [32minfo[39m: Local binary stopped !  !`

I runned sample few times and all was fine. But after the last update that was released a few hours ago I got this error.

Comment: Could you please share your project's package.json file?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?